# PayPal API Validation Error: Item amount must add up to specified amount subtotal (or total if amount details not specified)

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, paypal, payment

I'm currently having an error(as mentioned in the title). I don't know what's wrong or which line I'm having problems with. I'm sure all the values mentioned in the error are the same but it still pops up the same error.

My aim is to make the all the values the same to solve the error.

Here's the full description of my error:

```
{
  "name": "https://stackoverflow.com/VALIDATION_ERROR",
  "details": [
    {
      "field": "transactions[0]",
      "issue": "Item amount must add up to specified amount subtotal (or total if amount details not specified)"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Invalid request - see details",
  "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors",
  "debug_id": "67a354f1a8fc7"
}
```

Please help!

Here are my codes for reference:

```
// scList has 2 values inside.
List<UserShoppingCartDAO> scList = UserShoppingCartDAO.GetCartOfUser(uID);

List<Item> itms = new List<Item>();
ItemList itemList = new ItemList();
decimal deliveryCharges = 0;
string deliveryChargesStr = "";
decimal postagePackingCost = 0;
decimal examPaperPrice = 0;
int quantityOfExamPapers = 0;
decimal subtotal = 0;
decimal total = 0;
var transactionDetails = new Details();
var transactionAmount = new Amount();
Transaction tran = new Transaction();

for (int iCounter = 0; iCounter < scList.Count; iCounter++)
{
    Product p = Product.getProduct(scList[iCounter].ProductID.ToString());
    deliveryCharges = p.price * 0.05m;
    deliveryChargesStr = deliveryCharges.ToString();
    postagePackingCost = 10m;
    examPaperPrice = p.price;
    quantityOfExamPapers = scList[iCounter].ProductQuantity;
    subtotal = (quantityOfExamPapers * examPaperPrice);
    total = subtotal + postagePackingCost;

    var examPaperItem = new Item();
    examPaperItem.name = p.productName;
    examPaperItem.currency = "SGD";
    examPaperItem.price = total.ToString();
    examPaperItem.sku = p.productID.ToString();
    examPaperItem.description = p.productDesc;
    examPaperItem.quantity = quantityOfExamPapers.ToString();

    itms.Add(examPaperItem);
    itemList.items = itms;

    //  var transactionDetails = new Detail
    transactionDetails.tax = "0";
    if (transactionDetails.shipping == null)
    {
        transactionDetails.shipping = postagePackingCost.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        decimal total2 = decimal.Parse(transactionDetails.shipping) + postagePackingCost;
        transactionDetails.shipping = total2.ToString();
    }

    if (transactionDetails.subtotal == null)
    {
        transactionDetails.subtotal = subtotal.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        decimal total2 = decimal.Parse(transactionDetails.subtotal) + subtotal;
        transactionDetails.subtotal = total2.ToString();
    }

    //transactionDetails.shipping = postagePackingCost.ToString();
    //transactionDetails.subtotal = subtotal.ToString("0.00");

    //    var transactionAmount = new Amount();
    transactionAmount.currency = "SGD";

    if (transactionAmount.total == null)
    {
        transactionAmount.total = total.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        decimal total2 = decimal.Parse(transactionAmount.total) + total;
        transactionAmount.total = total2.ToString();
    }

    transactionAmount.details = transactionDetails;

    //   Transaction tran = new Transaction();

    tran.description = scList[0].ProductDescription;
    tran.invoice_number = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    tran.amount = transactionAmount;

    //    transaction.item_list = new List<Item>();
    tran.item_list = itemList;
    transactionList.Add(tran);
}
transactionList.Remove(transactionList[1]);
//Authenticate with paypal
var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();
var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();

//Get APIContent Object
var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);

var payer = new Payer();
payer.payment_method = "paypal";

var redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
redirectUrls.cancel_url = "http://localhost60681/Cancel.aspx";
redirectUrls.return_url = "http://localhost:60681/CompletePurchase.aspx";

var payment = Payment.Create(apiContext, new Payment
{

    intent = "sale",
    payer = payer,
    transactions = transactionList,
    redirect_urls = redirectUrls
});

Session["paymentId"] = payment.id;

foreach (var link in payment.links)
{
    if (link.rel.ToLower().Trim().Equals("approval_url"))
    {
        Response.Redirect(link.href);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me... What exactly is your question?

Comment: Even though I checked and all the values are the same (unit price, quantity, subtotal, total), it still gives me this error. How do I solve this? Is this a logic error?  @VDWWD

Comment: Step through each amount in `Payment` and check their values. I see in your code that you do `ToString()` on several occasions on a decimal value, that could be the cause. And you remove a transaction from the list at some point, that could also be the cause.

Comment: PS are you also Bryan Toh? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463152/c-sharp-paypal-integration-issue-with-payment-method.